# Is the following implementation making my code parallel?

Tags: go, parallel-processing

I had an assignment in Go to parallelize a given loop of a code. I am unsure whether or not my code is parallel.

I tried simply dividing the array i had into two halves, and used a go routine on both halves.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Body struct {
    x, y, vx, vy, mass float64
    r, g, b uint
}

func main() {
    var count uint
    var radius float64
    done := make(chan bool)
    fmt.Scan(&count, &radius)
    bodies := make([]Body, count)
    for i := range bodies {
        b := &bodies[i]
        fmt.Scan(&b.x, &b.y, &b.vx, &b.vy, &b.mass, &b.r, &b.g, &b.b)
    }

    updatedBodies := make([]Body, count)
    copy(updatedBodies, bodies)
    mid := len(updatedBodies)/2


    go func(){
    for i := range updatedBodies[mid:] {
        b := &updatedBodies[i+mid]
        for _, ob := range bodies {
            dx, dy := ob.x - b.x, ob.y - b.y
            if dist := math.Sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy); dist > 1 { // far enough
                accel := 0.0000000000667 * ob.mass / (dist * dist * dist)
                b.vx += accel * dx
                b.vy += accel * dy
            }
        }
        b.x += b.vx
        b.y += b.vy

    }
    done <- true
}()
    go func(){
        for i := range updatedBodies[:mid] {
        b := &updatedBodies[i]
        for _, ob := range bodies {
            dx, dy := ob.x - b.x, ob.y - b.y
            if dist := math.Sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy); dist > 1 { // far enough
                accel := 0.0000000000667 * ob.mass / (dist * dist * dist)
                b.vx += accel * dx
                b.vy += accel * dy
            }
        }
        b.x += b.vx
        b.y += b.vy

    }
    done <- true
}()

    <- done
    <- done
    fmt.Println(count)
    fmt.Println(radius)
    for _, b := range updatedBodies {
        fmt.Println(b.x, b.y, b.vx, b.vy, b.mass, b.r, b.g, b.b)
    }
}
```

```
for i := range updatedBodies {
        b := &updatedBodies[i]
        for _, ob := range bodies {
            dx, dy := ob.x - b.x, ob.y - b.y
            if dist := math.Sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy); dist > 1 { // far enough
                accel := 0.0000000000667 * ob.mass / (dist * dist * dist)
                b.vx += accel * dx
                b.vy += accel * dy
            }
        }
        b.x += b.vx
        b.y += b.vy

    }
```

I asked a professor about the code he said I had to recursively run a go routine to make the loop parallel.

Comment: The second snippet is the code or loop in the first snippet that i had to parallelize.

Comment: The objective was to update all the "bodies" in parallel using go routines.

Comment: One way to do this would be to loop over every item in the list and spawn a goroutine for each one. Though, as your professor mentioned recursion, he might have in mind a binary divide-and-conquer approach: spawn a goroutine for each half of the list, in each of those goroutines spawn another for each half of the half, etc.

Comment: If your assignment is literally to make this parallel, then your professor doesn't understand Go. Go doesn't give you the option to parallelize things. It only lets you run things concurrently, which Go itself may, or may not, choose to run in parallel. Watch [this](https://blog.golang.org/concurrency-is-not-parallelism), and tell your professor to do the same.

Comment: Your task is to make the outer loop parallel such that all bodies are updated in parallel. You must use goroutines and must ensure that no concurrency isseus (shared memory) are introduced and the output is correct. Lambda functions are not required but will make this part very simple.
These are the exact wordings.

Comment: That exact wording is confused. :) You can write concurrent code, which may or may not execute in parallel. There's no guarantee that your code will run in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does run concurrently*, but not necessarily in a very optimal way.  You've essentially split your workload into two, and you're running both halves concurrently.

> [The professor] said I had to recursively run a go routine to make the loop parallel.

This is not true, but I don't know the exact words your professor said, so he may not have been lying to you.  He apparently has some sort of recursive solution in mind. I wouldn't use recursion here, but it would be one way.

It's hard to provide the answer your professor is looking for. The best advice is to ask your professor to explain his intentions.

*concurrency is not parallelism. Please read/watch [this](https://blog.golang.org/concurrency-is-not-parallelism).

Comment: Thanks this does help me. Will post any update I get.